# How to manage versioning in interdependent libraries?

Tags: code-reuse

I have a number of libraries that I have developed for various projects, e.g. a web server, some computation tools, some logging tools, etc.

These reside in different parts of my drive.

When I have a project that uses a few of these, I (rudimentarily) just copy the source files from the library's folder to the project's source directory, and compile it all together.  If I make some changes to a library, I then copy it back to the main repository for the library.  This then causes problems as I may want to update the library everywhere else that it is used.

What is a better way to manage this cleanly?

In Visual Studio you can have multiple "projects" which are interdependent, but you have to load all of them in the same solution.  I want something like this, but not dependent on Visual Studio, and without having to load everything I've ever written whenever I do some work.

Comment: Basically, you are looking for a dependency manager and an artefact repository.

Answer (score 1):

Packages and package managers are meant to be used for this.

For .NET / Visual Studio, that means [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/).

[Creating new NuGet package](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio?tabs=netcore-cli) is trivial nowadays with available tooling. And hosting on NuGet is free.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I used Visual Studio as an example -- my code isn't actually .NET, are there cross-platform alternatives?

Comment: Java has Maven, NodeJS has NPM, Python as Pim, etc. You have to search for it a bit.